# PHP SESSION variable assigning value to itself even before i declare it?

Tags: php

I have a session variable `$_SESSION['divcontent']` in one of my pages.

I have a main page that calls an ajax function which runs the page with the above mentioned variable.

I have an `if (!isset)` clause which is only supposed to trigger if the above session variable is not yet set.

However it's not triggering at all. So i put an echo statement at the very beginning of this file to echo the variable, and it says its value is 0.

I have not referenced this variable in any other page. I changed the echo statement to echo a different variable not mentioned anywhere and it returned a variable not found error, as it should. I am viewing the page in live mode in dreamweaver. Each time i run it the session variables should reset to undeclared, shouldnt they?

Why is my variable self-instantiating at value = 0?

Comment: the session variable is created upon `session_start();` you must be setting this variable for use in a different page or somewhere on the page otherwise it would throw an `undefined offset` error

Comment: Ok, i found out that it must be dreamweaver maintaining the session variable value. I changed the value to 3 at the end of the script, closed the dreamweaver live viewer and relaunched it, and the value was 3. Now i just need to find out how to stop this.

Comment: But that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Test it in a real browser. Dreamweaver is awful for testing things in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave any site, but the browser is still open (if there are no windows open but a browser process is open), it is still possible to maintain the same session.

The one thing I like to do for testing session variables is to open Chrome in incognito mode and try the site there.